# Ivy task 'install' not copying/installing documents

Tags: ant, ivy

I am using ivy with ant to build multiple modules. I need to publish some documents (.docx files). But when I need to install from one ivy repository to other they are not being copied. How do I tell ivy to copy those documents when using install task.

Publications:

```
<publications>
  <artifact name="find" type="jar" conf="core" />
  <artifact name="Documentation" type="res" ext="docx"/>
  <artifact name="Dep_report" type="res" ext="xml"/>
</publications>
```

Install task call to copy artifacts from one ivy repository to another:

```
<ivy:install organisation="${ivy.organisation}" module="${ivy.module}" 
        revision="${ivy.revision}" from="shared" to="released" overwrite="true" />
```

Also, I must add that publishing to shared and installing it to released ivy repository don't happen on the same ant call. I added < ivy:resolve /> before calling install and it didn't help either (Do I need to add any attributes to ivy:resolve call??). Do I need to specify dependency on the documentation in ivy.xml file? Install copies jar file and ivy.xml fine but not the docs or xml files. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not adding conf on artifacts. I needed to add conf="core" for both docx and xml file publication:

```
<publications>
 <artifact name="find" type="jar" conf="core" />
 <artifact name="Documentation" type="res" ext="docx" conf="core" />
 <artifact name="Dep_report" type="res" ext="xml" conf="core" />
</publications>
```

Also, for ivy:install needed to add conf="core" as follows:

```
<ivy:install organisation="${ivy.organisation}" module="${ivy.module}" 
    revision="${ivy.revision}" from="shared" to="released" overwrite="true" conf="core" />
```